# hadoop-common build using maven failed due to missing artifact jdk.tools:jar

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

trying to build the hadoop-common project using 
the command,

```
  mvn generate-sources generate-test-sources
```

The build failed with error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hadoop-annotations: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/../lib/tools.jar -> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The tools.jar is missing in openjdk-11 version.

Comment: There is a problem within the given build cause it tries to use tools.jar which does not exist and will not work with JDK9+ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop [requires Java 8 to build](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP/Hadoop+Java+Versions), still.

Java 11 progress can be tracked at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15338

Comment: Installed openjdk-8. Thanks